# Difference between recordset and sqlreader

Tags: .net, ado.net

Difference and similarities between recordset in asp and datareader in asp.net

Comment: Do you mean a dataset and a datareader?

Comment: If you don't take the time to phrase out a well-defined question nobody's going to spend time answering it.

Comment: I think they mean the difference between an ADO recordset and a .NET DataReader.

Comment: @Michael - perhaps the OP is not a native English speaker?
@Richard - I think you're right, now if only I hadn't mentally blocked out everything about classic ASP =)

Answer (score 3):

If you are comparing ADO recordset to ADO.NET DataReader, then Dino Esposito has [a very old article on MSDN comparing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810288.aspx) some of the differences- it also cover the DataSet.

Comment: up vote for the article reference. I was looking for a technical comparison but now I understand that one is the evolution of the other so I guess that explains it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

A `DbDataReader` is similar to a read-only forward-only `RecordSet`.

A `DataTable` is similar to a disconnected `RecordSet`.